# Error While trying to create cookie using requests module

Tags: python, session-cookies, python-requests

I want to capture the cookies for later logging into the website, precisely I need to get that , X-CSRFToken thing and pass it later in post command, here is my piece of code

```
import requests

url = "https://accounts.coursera.org/signin?post_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.coursera.org%2F"

r = requests.get(url)
r.cookies['example_cookie_name']
```

The error is :

```
KeyError: "name='example_cookie_name', domain=None, path=None"
```

Comment: Are you sure the page given provides the `X-CSRFToken` cookie? I've opened the website via Chrome and there is no such cookie.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have that field(key) in your cookies.

For your task, I suggest using the requests' [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects), it makes life a lot easier.

Comment: I tried it , but it still doesn't works :( Can you test it on your machine please?

Comment: @user3051961 There is no cookie in the response, from my test.